# h2o starting on YARN not working

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, h2o

When I start H2o on a cdh cluster I get the following error.  I downloaded everything formt he wbesite and followed the tutorial. The command I ran was

```
hadoop jar h2odriver.jar -nodes 2 -mapperXmx 1g -output hdfsOutputDirName
```

It shows that containers are not being used.  It's not clear what settings these would be on hadoop.  I have given all settings memory.  It's the 0.0 for memory that doesnt make sense, and why are the containers not using memory.  Is the cluster even running now?

```
----- YARN cluster metrics -----
Number of YARN worker nodes: 3

----- Nodes -----
Node: http://data-node-3:8042 Rack: /default, RUNNING, 1 containers used, 1.0 / 6.0 GB used, 1 / 4 vcores used
Node: http://data-node-1:8042 Rack: /default, RUNNING, 0 containers used, 0.0 / 6.0 GB used, 0 / 4 vcores used
Node: http://data-node-2:8042 Rack: /default, RUNNING, 0 containers used, 0.0 / 6.0 GB used, 0 / 4 vcores used

----- Queues -----
Queue name:            root.default
    Queue state:       RUNNING
    Current capacity:  0.00
    Capacity:          0.00
    Maximum capacity:  -1.00
    Application count: 0

Queue 'root.default' approximate utilization: 0.0 / 0.0 GB used, 0 / 0 vcores used

----------------------------------------------------------------------

WARNING: Job memory request (2.2 GB) exceeds queue available memory capacity (0.0 GB)
WARNING: Job virtual cores request (2) exceeds queue available virtual cores capacity (0)

----------------------------------------------------------------------

For YARN users, logs command is 'yarn logs -applicationId application_1462681033282_0008'
```

Comment: You should execute this command to see the detail:yarn logs -applicationId application_1462681033282_0008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following changes in Cloudera Manager yarn configuration

```
Setting                                     Value
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores    8 
yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores        4
yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores        4
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb        16 GB
```

Comment: It seems ok, and is it still failing?

Answer (score 3):

You should setup your default queue to have available resources to run 2nodes cluster.

See warnings:

1. `WARNING: Job memory request (2.2 GB) exceeds queue available memory capacity (0.0 GB)`

   - you ask 1GB per node (+overhead) but there is no available resources in the YARN queue
2. `WARNING: Job virtual cores request (2) exceeds queue available virtual cores capacity (0)`

   - you ask for 2 virtual cores but no cores are available in your default queue

Please check YARN documentation - for example setup of capacity scheduler and max available resources:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html

Comment: Its not clear at all which adjustments to make.  I have already adjusted all of those xml values and there is no difference.