# h2o on hadoop cluster doesn't work

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, h2o

I'm trying run h2o on hadoop:

- hadoop 2.7.1 (single node)
- h2o driver - h2o-3.10.4.3-mapr5.1

with the following command:

`hadoop jar h2odriver.jar -nodes 1 -mapperXmx 6g -output hdfsOutputDirName`

and getting this error:

```html
----- YARN cluster metrics -----
Number of YARN worker nodes: 1

----- Nodes -----
Node: http://DESKTOP-BPF0VCF:8042 Rack: /default-rack, RUNNING, 0 containers used, 0,0 / 16,0 GB used, 0 / 4 vcores used

----- Queues -----
Queue name:            default
    Queue state:       RUNNING
    Current capacity:  0,00
    Capacity:          1,00
    Maximum capacity:  1,00
    Application count: 0

Queue 'default' approximate utilization: 0,0 / 16,0 GB used, 0 / 4 vcores used

----------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR: Unable to start any H2O nodes; please contact your YARN administrator.

       A common cause for this is the requested container size (6,6 GB)
       exceeds the following YARN settings:

           yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb
           yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb

----------------------------------------------------------------------

For YARN users, logs command is 'yarn logs -applicationId application_1492203365290_0001'
```

Here's my yarn-site.xml:

```html
<configuration>
   <property>
       <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
       <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
       <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
   </property>
      <property>
       <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
       <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler</value>
   </property>

   <property>
       <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
       <value>16384</value>
   </property>

   <property>
       <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
       <value>16384</value>
   </property>

   <property>
       <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
       <value>8</value>
   </property>

   <property>
       <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
       <value>4</value>
   </property>
   
</configuration>
```

So, it's obvious that memory is enough, but it still doesn't work.
This post didn't help too:
[h2o starting on YARN not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096589/h2o-starting-on-yarn-not-working)

Comment: The error message is misleading to find the root cause of your problem as you do have enough memory. Please run the command "yarn logs -applicationId application_1492203365290_0001" to get the logs and attache those logs here. It will be interesting to see if logs are even created or not.

Comment: Will you please check the following settings and provide their values as well - mapreduce.map.memory.mb, mapreduce.map.java.opts, yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb

Comment: Are you able to run any other mapreduce jobs?  I can see your applicationId ends in _0001, which means this might be the first job you've ever tried to run.  Rest assured, many, many people have gotten this to work (with properly configured Hadoop environments).  Getting these environments up and running can be tricky, so reaching out the the MapR Sales Engineer supporting you would be a good option.

Comment: Did you manage to make it run? After more than 2 years, seems to keep happening :(